# Frozen coefficient method (von Neumann stability analysis)

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, stability

Earlier it was considered that frozen coefficients method for Neumann stability analysis for finite difference scheme is more heuristic than rigorous. But I have read some information in a book by Gustafsson,Kreiss,Oliger that there are some conditions, which give us possibility to use frozen coefficients+Neumann analysis at the level of full rigor. As a book didn't give any reference, could you help me to find these conditions?

Comment: Cross-posted from: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186760/frozen-coefficient-method-von-neumann-stability-analysis

Comment: Does the book mention anything about the possibility of applying von Neumann + frozen coefficient on PDE with Neumann Boundary Conditions? Thanks!